# Angular Scope, mystery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have two directives, **Isolated** and **Shared**, the **Isolated** directive pass the two-way binding directly to the **Shared** directive but the **Shared** directive is not using the **Isolated** scope, is creating its own.

The objective is that the **Isolated** directive should respond to changes in the two-way bindings when the **Shared** directive changes them.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="main as $ctrl">
    <h3>Main data: {{$ctrl.data.bind}}</h3>
    <isolated bind="$ctrl.data.bind"></isolated>
  </div>
</body>

angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", function() {
  this.data = {
    bind: 123
  }
})
.directive("isolated", function() {
return {
  scope: {
    bind: '='
  },
  bindToController: true,
  template: '<div><h3>Parent directive data: {{$ctrl.bind}}</h3> </div>'
            + '<input type="text" shared ng-model="$ctrl.bind" />',
  controller: function() {
    this.changed = function() {
      console.log('Data changed: ' + this.bind);
    }
  },
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  link: {
    pre: function($scope) {
      console.log("Parent data: " + $scope.$ctrl.bind);
    }
  }
}
})
.directive("shared", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: {
      ngModel: '^'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    link: function($scope) {
      console.log('Current data in shared: ' + $scope.$ctrl.bind)
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.$postLink = function() {
        this.ngModel.$modelValue = 321;
      }
    },
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
  }
});
```

Here I have a  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6avj4QCUXveQpIV8r11J?p=preview)

Comment: problem is with your shared directive. `controllerAs: '$ctrl'` change this to `vm` load the value in text box.

But postlink function doesn't change value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gourav Garg is correct. Due to the shared scope, the second directive declaration is overriding the `$scope.$ctrl` field. The `controllerAs` property in the second declaration is unneeded anyways, as you never access the controllers properties within the template. If you do end up needing the second directives controller information within your template, you need to declare it's name as something other than `$ctrl`, or, better yet, use `require` syntax to require the second directive on the first directive. That will bind the second directive's controller to a property on the first directive's controller.

For more information on require, see the "Creating Directives That Communicate" section of the angular directive guide [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Best of luck!